# Mocking java.util.logging.Logger while using jersey

Tags: java, logging, mocking, jersey, mockito

We are using maven, jersey, Mockito in our project, with java.util.logging for Logs. While running Junit test with mocked objects, log.log() method throwing InvalidUseOfMatchersException. Below is the sample code.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class Sample{

    @Inject
    Logger log;

    public String runLog(String name){
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Name = "+name);
    return "name";
    }
}

public class SampleTest{

    @InjectMocks
    Sample sample;

    @Mock
    Logger log;


    public void setup() throws Exception(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initiMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRunLog(){
        doNothing().when(log).log(any(Level.class), anyString());
        String s = sample.runLog(anyString());
        assertNotNull(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
String s = sample.runLog(anyString());
```

You can use `anyString` (and all other matcher methods) only in `verify` and `when` methods.

If you don't care about exact value you pass then pass some constant or random string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually worked for me. But if I comment the logs and other java code works perfect even with anyString(). Is there any specific reason for this??

Comment: Yes, but to explain it I need to explain how mocks works internally. I don't think I'm able because it involve tons of MAGIC.